# Mudar comportamento Maximize com WndProc ou Override

Tags: vb.net

Eu tenho um form sem borda e preciso Maximizar e restaurar ele, mas como já sabem se eu usar `Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized` ele fica em Full Screen.

Eu já tenho o como resolver:

`Dim tela As Screen = Screen.FromPoint(Me.Location)                                    Me.Size = New Size(tela.WorkingArea.Size.Width, tela.WorkingArea.Size.Height)
Me.Location = tela.WorkingArea.Location 'New Point(0, 0)`

Eu não gostaria de fazer isso pôs eu teria que salvar o estado (local e tamanho) antes do Form ser "Maximizado" pelo código acima, para restaurar ele depois. O que eu queria é que ele executasse o código acima e pensasse que está Maximizado.

Eu já tinha usado o `WndProc` e `Protected Overrides ReadOnly Property` para resolver alguns outros problemas. Ex:

```
'Minimiza da Taskbar
Private Const WS_MINIMIZEBOX As Integer = &H20000
Private Const CS_DBLCLKS As Integer = &H8

Protected Overrides ReadOnly Property CreateParams As CreateParams
    'Minimiza da Taskbar
    Get
        Dim cp As CreateParams = MyBase.CreateParams
        cp.Style = cp.Style Or WS_MINIMIZEBOX
        cp.ClassStyle = cp.ClassStyle Or CS_DBLCLKS
        Return cp
    End Get
End Property
```

E

```
    Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As Message)
        Dim p As Point = Me.PointToClient(MousePosition)

        If m.Msg = &H84 Then
            Dim pos As Point = New Point(m.LParam.ToInt32() And &HFFFF, m.LParam.ToInt32() >> 16)
            pos = Me.PointToClient(pos)

            'Move Form
            If  pos.Y <= 10 Then
                 m.Result = CType(2, IntPtr)
                Return
           End If
End Sub
```

Mas eu não sei o "valor" do maximize, eu já fiz algumas buscas, mas não encontrei o valor. Então resumindo a pergunta como eu posso dar um "`Override`" para que quando eu maximize o programa com `Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized` ele execute o código eu que mostrei no inicio? E se possível uma lista com os "valores" existentes, pôs ainda há alguns que eu preciso, mas não consigo achar.